# Reference in C++

Tags: c++, reference

Suppose that we have these two situations?

```
int p = 10;
int& q = p;
```

and

```
int p = 10;
int q = p;
```

Are not these two situations the same? I am little confused with the purpose of references, so please explain difference in these two.

Comment: isocpp have a nice [article on this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int p = 10;
int& q = p;
```

In this case, `q` is for all practical purposes an alias for `p`. They share a memory location. If you modify `q`, you modify `p`. If you modify `p`, you modify `q`. `q` is just a different name for `p`.

```
int p = 10;
int q = p;
```

Here, `q` gets a copy of the value of `p` at the time when `q` is initialized. Afterwards, `q` and `p` are completely independent. Changing `q` does not affect `p` and changing `p` does not affect `q`.

Comment: Thank you @dhke. Good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, if you change the value of `q` it will not affect the value of `p`. In the first case, changing the value of `q` will also change the value of `p` and vice versa.

```
$ cat ref.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  int p = 10;
  int q = p;
  int s = 10;
  int& t = s;
  q = 11;
  t = 11;
  std::cout << p << std::endl;
  std::cout << q << std::endl;
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
  s = 12;
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

$ g++ ref.cpp
$ ./a.out
10
11
11
11
12
12
$
```

Answer (score 1):

In Second case `p q` are two independent integers. in first case both `p q` will point to same location in the memory. as you asked for the purpose of references. please go through `call by value & call by reference`. you can understand the use of references. go through the page. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm

Answer (score 0):

Changing a reference will change the underlying variable.  This can be useful
in situations like:

```
int count_odd = 0;
int count_even = 0;
int i;

    ....

    // Create a reference to either count_odd or count_even.
    int& count = (i%1) ? count_odd : count_even;
    // Now update the right count;
    count++;
```

This is rather artificial, but it becomes more useful with rather more
complicated situations.